# Trying to replace something in a string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace the Placeholder in the string with an integer. It worked when I used strings of words, but I can't get this to work with integers.

```
def replacer(string, replacement):
    string = re.sub(r"Placeholder", replacement, string)
    return string


replacer("SELECT Nettogewinn FROM GUV WHERE company_id=Placeholder", company_id)
```

Comment: Why not just use `string.replace('Placeholder', replacement)`?

Comment: You won't be able to get it to work with _integers_ because regexes operate on strings only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

`str(replacement)`

in your function to convert the int of float to a string.